# How to upload multiple audio file in react but sending only 3 POST request

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I want to select 100 audio file at a time but want to hit only 3 api call at a time. Once these 3 files uploaded (pass or fail) then only other 3 api request will be sent.

Basically I am providing a input field of file type:

```
<input type="file" multiple name="file" className="myform"
                    onChange={handleFileChange}
                    accept="audio/wav"
                    />
```

and I am storing it as array into a state.
Below this I am providing an UPLOAD button.
When user hit on upload, I want to send 3 POST request using axios. once all 3 done either fail or pass then only next 3 should go.

Comment: Do you need to send each file in a separate request?

Comment: no only 3 at a time

Comment: but each 3 of them is individual request.

Comment: You're not being very clear. Do you want to upload 3 files in a single request or 3 individual requests with 1 file each?

Comment: At a time I will hit api that contains one request.
this way only 3 request will be made simultaneously .
Once these 3 completed then next 3 in same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by iterating the `FileList` collection in groups of 3 and sending the requests in parallel using [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled).

Simply because I cannot recommend Axios, here's a version using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```js
const BATCH_SIZE = 3;

const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([]);
const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

const handleFileChange = (e) => {
  setFileList(Array.from(e.target.files)); // just a guess
};

const handleUploadClick = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setUploading(true);
  const files = [...fileList]; // avoid mutation during long uploading process

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += BATCH_SIZE) {
    const result = await Promise.allSettled(
      files.slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE).map(async (file) => {
        const body = new FormData();
        body.append("file", file);
        const res = await fetch(UPLOAD_URL, { method: "POST", body });
        return res.ok ? res : Promise.reject(res);
      })
    );
    const passed = result.filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled");
    console.log(
      `Batch ${i + 1}: ${
        passed.length
      } of ${BATCH_SIZE} requests uploaded successfully`
    );
  }

  setUploading(false);
};
```

`Promise.allSettled()` will let you continue after each set of 3 are uploaded, whether they pass or fail.

This method makes 3 separate requests with 1 file each.

---

With Axios, it would look like this (just replacing the `for` loop)

```js
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += BATCH_SIZE) {
  const result = await Promise.allSettled(
    files
      .slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE)
      .map((file) => axios.postForm(UPLOAD_URL, { file }))
  );
  const passed = result.filter(({ status }) => status === "fulfilled");
  console.log(
    `Batch ${i + 1}: ${
      passed.length
    } of ${BATCH_SIZE} requests uploaded successfully`
  );
}
```

Axios' `postForm()` method is available from v1.0.0. See https://github.com/axios/axios#files-posting

---

If you want to send 3 files in a single request, it would look like this for Fetch

```js
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += BATCH_SIZE) {
  const body = new FormData();
  files.slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE).forEach((file) => {
    body.append("file", file); // use "file[]" for the first arg if required
  });
  try {
    const res = await fetch(UPLOAD_URL, { method: "POST", body });
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
    }
    console.log(`Batch ${i + 1} passed`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(`Batch ${i + 1} failed`, err);
  }
}
```

and this for Axios

```js
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += BATCH_SIZE) {
  try {
    await axios.postForm(
      {
        file: files.slice(i, i + BATCH_SIZE),
      },
      {
        formSerializer: {
          indexes: null, // set to false if you need "[]" added
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(`Batch ${i + 1} passed`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(`Batch ${i + 1} failed`, err.response?.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Phil my backend doesnot support postForm().
It is asking for post only. Also note 'Content-Type': 'application/json'

Comment: @MDALISHAHANSHAH `postForm` is an Axios method that sends a POST request with `content-type: multipart/form-data`. It runs on your client and has nothing to do with the server. Also, you cannot upload files with an `application/json` content-type so I have no idea what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of JavaScript's for loop and Promise.all functions to achieve this. First, you will need to divide your files array into chunks of 3. You can do this using a for loop and the slice method. Next, you can use Promise.all to send all the requests in parallel, and only move on to the next set of requests once all the promises in the current set have been resolved. Here's some sample code that demonstrates this approach:

```
const chunkSize = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += chunkSize) {
  const fileChunk = files.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
  const promises = fileChunk.map(file => {
    return axios.post('/api/upload', { file });
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
}
```

This will send 3 post request at a time and will wait until all the request are completed before sending another 3 api request.

You can also use useState hook with useEffect to set the state of files that are uploaded and use a variable to keep track of number of files uploaded.

```
const [uploadedFiles, setUploadedFiles] = useState([]);
const [uploadCount, setUploadCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  if (uploadCount === files.length) {
    // all files have been uploaded
    return;
  }
  const chunkSize = 3;
  const fileChunk = files.slice(uploadCount, uploadCount + chunkSize);
  const promises = fileChunk.map(file => {
    return axios.post('/api/upload', { file });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(responses => {
    setUploadedFiles([...uploadedFiles, ...responses]);
    setUploadCount(uploadCount + chunkSize);
  });
}, [uploadCount]);
```

This code will work for you.

Comment: There's a couple of problems here... 1) You're trying to post a `File` as JSON which simply won't work. 2) OP said they want to continue uploading whether or not the previous attempts _"pass or fail"_. Using `Promise.all()` won't achieve that